# Swift - Getting tap location on a button which was created through custom UIView class

Tags: swift

I have a main scrollerview in my main `UIViewController` and a custom `UIView` class. This custom `UIView` class has few lines of code to create `Button` and `Label` programmatically. The action to be performed by `Button` click is working fine, but I also need to get the exact tap location (`CGPoint`) on the button as the button is long and tap x-coordinate is required for next actions. I tried few solutions got from **stackoverflow** and is working for other objects like `Label` and `Imageview` but doesn't work for button.

My custom UIView class:

```
import UIKit
class DrawProj: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let button = UIButton(type: .System) 
        button.frame = CGRectMake(24, 15, linewidth - 25, 20)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        button.addTarget(nil, action: "onButtonTap:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

And Code in main Viewcontroller

```
let DrawProjectLanes = DrawProj(frame: CGRect(x: startx, y: starty, width: endx , height: 50))
DrawProjectLanes.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
DrawProjectLanes.userInteractionEnabled = true
MainScroller.addSubview(DrawProjectLanes)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, custom UIView class will added as subview to the scrollerview in Main UIViewcontroller. In the end I will have a button created by custom UIView class on top of scrollerview and my goal is to perform some action on button tap (able to do using .addTraget) and also get the exact x-cordinate of the tap on button, not the scrollerview or main screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `touchesBegan` for this to work:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}
```

Then declare your `button` subview as a property:

```
class DrawProj: UIView {
    var button: UIButton!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        button = UIButton(type: .System) 
        button.frame = CGRectMake(24, 15, linewidth - 25, 20)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        button.addTarget(nil, action: "onButtonTap:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

In `touchesBegan`, do this to get the x position of the tap, relative to the button's frame:

```
let posX = touches.first!.locationInView(button).x
```

Then, you can use this `posX` variable however you want.

How to instantiate a view controller:

In the storyboard, select the VC that you would like to present. Go to the identity inspector, set a Storyboard ID for the VC:

[image]

Then in code,

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("put the storyboard ID that you set earlier here")
let topViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentationController
topViewController?.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for repling. I have tried this and I get the X coordinate when I click anywhere else on the UIView CGRect frame but not on the button. I added a UIlabel on the custom class and able to get X coordinate when tap on this UILabel. So I think the problem is only with Button.

Comment: @VijeshKk This is because `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIControl`, which works differently from other plain old views. Try setting `userInteractionEnabled` to false on the button

Comment: Thanks again. this works and able to get X-coordinate. but now my action: "onButtonTap:" doesnt work. 'action: "onButtonTap" is on main Viewcontroller and supposed to instantiate a new view controller. I am quite new to swift programming and I am so sorry for asking even too simple things.

Comment: @VijeshKk Why did you add the `onButtonTap` target? There is no need for that, you can just do all the things you want in the `touchesBegan` method! Just check whether the point touched is in the frame of the button using `if button.frame.conatins(touches.first!.locationInView(button))`

Comment: Ok, but this takes me back to the old problem I had, which is, instantiate another viewcontroller from UIView class. button.addTarget(nil, action: "onButtonTap:") helped to fix it but above case I am not sure how to instantiate another viewcontroller through touchesBegan in the UIView. it would be very helpful if you could guide me. thanks.

Comment: Edited, please take a look. @VijeshKk

Comment: thanks for the prompt responses.. I did as you advised but I am getting error "value of type 'UIPresentationController' has no member 'presentViewController'.. Sorry for keep troubling.

Comment: @VijeshKk Oops! My bad! Change `presentationController` to `presentedViewController`